# TTPickerTextField DataSource? How do I create my own DataSource?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, three20

for my iPhone Project, I woud love to use the TTpickerTextField from [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) to let the User select a contact from the Addressbook. While I’m really new to cocoa, I don’t understand how to use the Addressbook as a DataSource. As far as I understand, I have to create my own DataSource, that means, get every entry from the Addressbook and put it in my own DataSource, correct? But what Delegate/Protocol do I have to implement in my class, so that my class is a DataSource? Or am I on the wrong way? Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you so much

dragi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just from looking at the headers, but TTPickerTextField is a subclass of TTSearchTextField, which has this property:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) id<TTTableViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

So, I would expect that your custom object should adopt the TTTableViewDataSource protocol.

Comment: Could you maybe post a example on how you implemented the TTTableViewDataSource protocol to make it work with the Addressbook, Im a newbie and cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ken says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333398/ttpickertextfield-datasource-how-do-i-create-my-own-datasource/1333489#1333489), you'll want a class that implements the protocol `TTTableViewDataSource`, and then to set an instance of that class as your field's `dataSource` property.

Additionally, you'll want to review the [Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1), which will point you to the APIs you need to get data out of the Address Book itself in your datasource class.